# querying metadata from HTML page with SPARQL returns nothing

Tags: html, perl, sparql, rdf, microdata

I seem to be having some issue either using `HTML::HTML5::Microdata::Parser` or `RDF::Query` or with SPARQL syntax and semantics. I am interested in this bit from a [news site page](http://zpravy.idnes.cz/zacinaji-zapisy-do-prvnich-trid-dn3-/domaci.aspx?c=A160114_171615_domaci_zt).

```html
<div class="authors">
Autoři: <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><a rel="author" itemprop="url" class="name" href="http://vice.idnes.cz/novinari.aspx?idnov=2504" ><span itemprop="name">Zdeňka Trachtová</span></a></span>
,
<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><a rel="author" itemprop="url"  href="http://vice.idnes.cz/novinari.aspx?idnov=3495" ><span itemprop="additionalName">san</span></a><span class="h" itemprop="name">Sabina Netrvalová</span></span>
</div>
```

Here is my test code:

```perl
#! env perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTML::HTML5::Microdata::Parser;
use RDF::Query;
use IO::Handle;
use LWP::Simple;


STDOUT->binmode(":utf8");
STDERR->binmode(":utf8");

my $htmldoc = LWP::Simple::get(
    "http://zpravy.idnes.cz/zacinaji-zapisy-do-prvnich-trid-dn3-/domaci.aspx?c=A160114_171615_domaci_zt");
die "Could not fetch URL. $@" unless defined $htmldoc;

my $microdata = HTML::HTML5::Microdata::Parser->new (
    $htmldoc, $ARGV[0],
    {auto_config => 1, tdb_service => 1, xhtml_meta => 1, xhtml_rel => 1});
print STDERR "microdata->graph:\n", Dumper($microdata->graph), "\n";

my $query = RDF::Query->new(<<'SPARQL');
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
   ?author a schema:Person .
}
SPARQL

my $people = $query->execute($microdata->graph);
print STDERR "authors from RDF:\n", Dumper($people), "\n";
while (my $person = $people->next) {
    print STDERR "people: ", $person, "\n";
}
```

The options to the `HTML::HTML5::Microdata::Parser` were just my last ditch effort to make this work. (I have basically zero idea what I am doing.)

Any ideas how to make this work and get the authors' names?

Comment: In the end I have ended up using `HTML::Microdata` instead. It works for what I want to do with it. However, I am still interested in hearing about how to make the `HTML::HTML5::Microdata::Parser` plus SPARQL way work.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) and [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use v5.10;

BEGIN {
    binmode *STDOUT, ':utf8';
    binmode *STDERR, ':utf8';
}

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $url = "http://zpravy.idnes.cz/zacinaji-zapisy-do-prvnich-trid-dn3-/domaci.aspx?c=A160114_171615_domaci_zt";

my $dom = Mojo::UserAgent->new->get($url)->res->dom;

# Process all authors
for my $span ($dom->find('span[itemprop=author]')->each) {
    say $span->all_text;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Zdeňka Trachtová
san Sabina Netrvalová
```

For a short 8 minute tutorial on these modules, just check out [Mojocast episode 5](http://mojocasts.com/e5).